# Created images heights sometimes dont working

Tags: javascript

I creating image and i giving file location this image with random number.
I taking these images heights and i saving in sizes array. ıts happening in for loop.
This is generaly working but sometimes sizes being zero.
My codes:

```
let tests = [];
let sizes = [];
let deger;

for (let index = 0; index < 40; index += 1) {
    let img = new Image();
    
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if(random==0){
        deger = '/img/test-1.png';
        img.src = deger;
        sizes[index]=img.height;
        tests[index] = deger;

    }else if(random==1){
        deger = '/img/test-2.png';
        img.src = deger;
        sizes[index]=img.height;
        tests[index] = deger;
    }else{
        deger = '/img/test-3.png';
        img.src = deger;
        sizes[index]=img.height;
        tests[index] = deger;
    }

}
console.log(sizes);
```

like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image has not loaded yet so their will not be a height available. Instead you can use the [onload method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to add them to your array once they are loaded.

Also instead of assigning the sizes at an specific index you could just use the [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```js
let tests = [];
let sizes = [];
let deger;

for (let index = 0; index < 40; index += 1) {
    let img = new Image();
    
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if(random==0){
        deger = 'https://picsum.photos/200';
        img.src = deger;
        img.onload = function() {
          sizes.push(img.height);
          tests.push(deger);
          
          console.log(sizes);
        }
    }else if(random==1){
        deger = 'https://picsum.photos/300';
        img.src = deger;
        img.onload = function() {
          sizes.push(img.height);
          tests.push(deger);
          
          console.log(sizes);
        }
    }else{
        deger = 'https://picsum.photos/400';
        img.src = deger;
        img.onload = function() {
          sizes.push(img.height);
          tests.push(deger);
          
          console.log(sizes);
        }
    }

}
```